# How to store multiple values for a key in PHP array through loop?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have this code-

```
 $my_array = [];
    $fobj = new stdClass();
    
    for($i=1; i<10; i++){
      if(i<=5){
         $fobj->below_five = $i;
      }else{
         $fobj->above_five = $i;
      }
   }
```

I want the result something like this...

```
$my_array(
         below_five->array(1,2,3,4,5),
         above_five->array(6,7,8,9)
);
```

Comment: `$fobj->below_five[] = $i;` etc

Comment: Why don't use [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) ? like `$fobj->below_five = range(1,5);`

Comment: It's good but it didn't work as I want it will create 10 indexes in $my_array but I want only two that are below_five and above_five.

Comment: i don't understand why do you use object instead of simple `$my_array['below_five'] = range(1,5);$my_array['above_five'] = range(6,10);`, [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d6d368b4b56d84158d5889d128d27b321cc98a7)

Comment: It's just an alternative example I'm fetching some data from APIs and I wanna store the same key data in the same key that's why I'm using loop and object.

Comment: API will come like a multidimensional array so i don't see sense anyway :)